# The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well- formed

Tags: java, selenium, testng

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="Test">
   <classes>
      <class name="upskill.runners.RunnerClass"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

With this line tstng.xml file shows  error but if i delete this line then it doesn’t  show error.
how do i fix this problem?

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the error? Please edit your question and add details on the exception stack trace, where/how you are running your test, and also the TestNG version

Comment: In my MAVEN project on testng.xml file  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> this line come out read.

Comment: Please edit your question and context (details that I had suggested you add). Without those details, its hard to say what is going wrong.